# Is there a way to add subdomains or different domains for one iCloud Keychain entry?

Tags: icloud, password, keychain

I have my passwords stored on *ICloud* via *KeyChain* the thing is it has different entries for something like: `account.mywebsite.com` and yet another one for the very same account only on the address: `stuff.mywebstie.com`?

I've noticed there's a *where* entry in KeyChain, can I put more domains and subdomains there? And if so, how? Separated via space, comma or semicolon?

[image]

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I have the same question. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254501347?sortBy=best seems to indicate that Apple don't think this is a valid use case.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not a perfect answer, but since Apple don't seem to support this, using a product like [1Password](https://1password.com) allows you to specify multiple domains per user